# How to store modified rows of a grid in datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a table with `Item_id`,`Item_value`,`Item_size`,`Item_brand` which is the data source of my gridview and my gridview allows users to update the columns. Now i want to store all the modified rows in the grid to a table.

Like `List modifiedRecords = listStore.getModifiedRecords();` which gives a list of modified records do we have any function that stores the entire row of modified column to a data table??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Editable gridview by using Templetfields of gridview, use below code in your .aspx file:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ITEM ID">
                                     <EditItemTemplate>
                                         <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Item_Id") %>'></asp:Label>
                                     </EditItemTemplate>
                                     <ItemTemplate>
                                         <asp:Label ID="lblId2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Item_Id") %>'></asp:Label>
                                     </ItemTemplate>
                                     <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                 </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ITEM Value">
                                     <EditItemTemplate>
                                         <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemValue" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Item_Value") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                     </EditItemTemplate>
                                     <FooterTemplate>
                                         <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemNewValue" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                     </FooterTemplate>
                                     <ItemTemplate>
                                         <asp:Label ID="lblItemValue" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Item_Value") %>'></asp:Label>
                                     </ItemTemplate>
                                     <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Then first add a Dataset named DsItems linked to Item table and add following queries: 
Select Items Query: "Select Item_Id, Item_Value from TblItems"
Update Query in Dataset: "Update TblItems set Item_Value=@value where Item_Id=@id"
Now in your .cs file first call the reference to the DSItems,
like:

```
       using System;
       using System.Collections;
       using System.Collections.Generic;
       using System.Data;
       using System.Diagnostics;
       using System.ComponentModel;
       using YouApplication.DSItems;    //your dataset refernce




  Public Void LoadItems ()
   {
   TblItemTableAdapter item= new TblItemTableAdapter();
    DataTable items= item.GetItems();
   if (items.Rows.Count > 0) {
Gridview1.DataSource = allowances;
Gridview1.DataBind();
  }}

    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender,   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        try {

    TblItemTableAdapter item = new TblItemTableAdapter();

    int item_id = txtItemId.Text;
    TextBox txtItemValue =         (TextBox)grdContact.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txtItemValue");

      item.UpdateItems(txtItemValue.text, item_id);
      Gridview1.EditIndex = -1;
    LoadItems();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    lblStatus.Text = "Items Updated.";
}
   }
       protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender,       System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs e)
   {
GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
LoadItems();
   }

  protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
  {
GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
LoadItems();
   }
```

Hope this will help you. Please feel free to comment for further clarification don't forget to mark as an answer if that would help you.

Comment: this would work to get the table of only updated items but all i was asking for is a does a single line function exist for this kind of need???

Comment: It is really simple, Just paste the gridview code in aspx file and then rest in .cs file. Then feel free to contact if you are not clear in any part.

Comment: I have used your two fields Item_Id and Item_Value to populate and update by using the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might be also a possibility of updation of records.

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                   ConnectionString="<%$ Your Connection %>" 

  UpdateCommand="UPDATE [table_name] SET item_id=@item_id, item_value=@item_value,item_size=@item_size,item_brand =@item_brand WHERE(<Your Condition>)"
           >
               <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name=" item_id " />
        <asp:Parameter Name=" item_value " />
        <asp:Parameter Name=" item_size " />
        <asp:Parameter Name=" item_brand " />

        </UpdateParameters>
               </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

in c#

```
  protected void GridView1_RowUpdating1(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.Visible = true;
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Data Updated Succesfully')</script>");
}
```

Comment: i dont think you have got my question i have updated my grid but i want only the updated rows in a different datatable

Comment: @Sri So you want to store the updated records to the database ?